# MySqlCommand gets Stuck

Tags: mysql, database-connection

i'm trying to execute a Stored Procedure with the MySqlCommand object from the MySql.Data.dll component.

I can get a connection using the MySqlConnection, but when i try to use the MySqlCommand to execute my Stored Procedure, does not work, it does not do anything... Even the component does not send an error.

I tested the Stored Procedure in MySql FrontEnd and it work fine, returning all the rows in the database in least a second

This is my code

Dim pMySqlCn As New MySqlConnection
Dim pMySqlCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim pMySqlDr As MySqlDataReader
Dim pStrComando = "SpArticulosObtener"

With pMySqlCn
    .ConnectionString = "XXXX"
    Call .Open()
End With

pMySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(pStrComando, pMySqlCn)
pMySqlDr = pMySqlCmd.ExecuteReader 'Here is the problem... the execution stops here and never ends

Can you help me?

Comment: How can anyone help if you don't share any code or relevant errors? Edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... i found the problem... in my case the user that try to execute the procedure in my DataBase needs "SELECT" permission to MySql.Proc table... Even that, is so strange that the MySqlCommand dont show an error because of this, and stops the execution.